# Average class not compliling

Tags: java, arrays

I tried looking up my error problems and I cannot figure out where I went wrong with my code.

Objective:

This class will allow a user to enter 5 scores into an array. It will then rearrange the data in descending order and calculate the mean for the data set.

Attributes:

• data[]—the array which will contain the scores

• mean—the arithmetic average of the scores

Methods:

• Average—the constructor. It will allocate memory for the array. Use a for loop to repeatedly display a prompt for the user which should indicate that user should enter score number 1, score number 2, etc. Note: The computer starts counting with 0, but people start counting with 1, and your prompt should account for this. For example, when the user enters score number 1, it will be stored in indexed variable 0. The constructor will then call the selectionSort and the calculateMean methods.

• calculateMean—this is a method that uses a for loop to access each score in the array and add it to a running total. The total divided by the number of scores (use the length of the array), and the result is stored into mean.

• toString—returns a String containing data in descending order and the mean.

• selectionSort—his method uses the selection sort algorithm to rearrange the data set from highest to lowest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{ 
  private int [] data;
  private double mean;

  public Average()
  {
    data = new int[5];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter score #" + (index + 1) +  ": ");
      data[index] = keyboard.nextInt;
    }
    keyboard.close();
    return data;
  }


  /**
   * calculateMean Method
   */

  public static float calculateMean(int[] data)
  {
    int total = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
    {
      total += data[index];
    }
    float mean = ((float)total) / data.length;
    return mean;    
  }

  /**
   * selectionSort Method
   */

  public static void selectionSort(int[] data)
  {
    int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (data.length-1); startScan++)
    {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = data[startScan];
      for(index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
      {
        if (data[index] < minValue)
        {
          minValue = data[index];
          minIndex = index;
        }
      }
      data[minIndex] = data [startScan];
      data [startScan] = minValue;
    }
  }

  /**
   * toString method
   */

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] data = new int[5];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter score #" + (index + 1) + ": ");
      data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    selectionSort(data);
    float average = calculateMean(data);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    System.out.println("Average is " + average);
  }
}
```

Sorry everyone, I should've posted what and where my errors were. This is what I get when I compile:

Compilation completed.  The following files were not compiled:

4 errors found:
File: C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\Average.java  [line: 16]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable nextInt
  location: variable keyboard of type java.util.Scanner
File: C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\Average.java  [line: 19]
Error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
File: C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\Average.java  [line: 50]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable array
  location: class Average
File: C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\Average.java  [line: 78]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Average

Comment: Can you show the compile error you are getting?

Comment: You have semicolons `;` after each method definition. Remove them.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning anything in your constructor. Also you need to change `void` to whatever it is that you are returning `void calculateMean` should be `int calculateMean`

Comment: Take it easy guys. OP is very new to SO and so it seems to programming in Java. It's obvious this code won't even compile, but at least there was an effort.

Comment: @Liutauras You mean an effort in not telling where the errors are and which error messages OP gets?

Comment: @Tom I meant an effort to write a code, try to compile and ask for help. I come across questions like 'I want a class in Java which calculates average' questions way too often.

Comment: @Liutauras Well, "Why isn't my code working" questions are also considered a "bad question" and can be flagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are static and have unfortunate extra semi-colons, and mix method parameters and class variables indiscriminately. You can't return a value from a `void` method. When I fix the syntax errors (and move the array into your `main()` method) it seems to work. So, I think you wanted something like

```
class Average {
    /**
     * calculateMean Method
     */
    public static float calculateMean(int[] data) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            total += data[index];
        }
        float mean = ((float) total) / data.length;
        return mean;
    }

    /**
     * selectionSort Method
     */

    public static void selectionSort(int[] data) {
        int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;

        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (data.length - 1); startScan++) {
            minIndex = startScan;
            minValue = data[startScan];
            for (index = startScan + 1; index < data.length; index++) {
                if (data[index] < minValue) {
                    minValue = data[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }
            data[minIndex] = data[startScan];
            data[startScan] = minValue;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = new int[5];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            System.out.println("Enter score #" + (index + 1) + ": ");
            data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        selectionSort(data);
        float average = calculateMean(data);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        System.out.println("Average is " + average);
    }
}
```